# Regex s modifier, not working?

Tags: php

Okay, I am a noob to regex, and I am using this site for my regex primer:

Question: using the s modifier, the  code below is suppose to echo 4 as it has found 4 newline characters.

However, when I run this I get one(1), why?

[link text](http:///www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-Regex.html#1)

```
 <?php
 /*** create a string with new line characters ***/
    $string = 'sex'."\n".'at'."\n".'noon'."\n".'taxes'."\n";

    /*** look for a match using s modifier ***/
    echo preg_match("/sex.at.noon/s", $string, $matches);

    /*The above code will echo 4 as it has found 4 newline characters.*/

?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`preg_match_all()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) instead which doesn't stop after the first match.

> `preg_match()` returns the number of times pattern matches. That will be either 0 times (no match) or 1 time because preg_match() will stop searching after the first match. `preg_match_all()` on the contrary will continue until it reaches the end of subject . `preg_match()` returns `FALSE` if an error occurred. —[PHP.net](http://de3.php.net/preg_match)

However, the code will output still only `1` because what you are *matching* is the regex "sex.at.noon" and *not* a line break.

Comment: Thanks, totally forget about that either it's 0 times which means no match or a 1 which means there was a match. 
So why does the author state I am suppose to get 4, see  attached link?

Comment: That's a good question. I'd assume he simply made a mistake and previously matched something like `.$`

Answer (score 1):

[preg_match()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) will only ever return 0 or 1 because it stops after the first time the pattern matches.  If you use [preg_match_all()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) it will still return 1 because your pattern only matches once in the string you're matching against.

If you want the number of newlines via regex:

```
echo preg_match_all("/\n/m", $string, $matches);
```

Or via string functions:

```
echo substr_count($string, "\n");
```